# Wiring a quorum windmill fan with two wall switches no remote

Tags: ceiling-fan, installation

I am trying to wire a quorum windmill ceiling fan it has a wall switch with six speeds.  I have two outlets on the wall that makes the fan run.  I have a red wire black and white wire.  The switch has two wires  does the red wire that controls the two wall switches need to be capped only using the black and white

Comment: Can you post the installation instructions for your fan?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It's hard to know exactly what you mean; a bit of editing could make it much more likely that your question gets a good answer.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/92596/how-do-ceiling-fan-controllers-work